# css selector : all except ones in

Tags: css, css-selectors

I'm having trouble using css selector. I would like to select all class "container", that are not in a parent "nav" :

```
<body>
    <nav>
        <div class="container"></div>
    </nav>
    <div class="container"></div>
    <div class="container"></div>
    <div class="container"></div>
    ...
</body>
```

Is this possible using css selector ?

SOLUTION : the solution (thx Noah) : `:not(nav) > .container {/** out your v=css here */}`. This work if .container is direct child of nav element.

Comment: No AFAIK. You can overwrite the styles though, like `.container{ background: red; } nav .container { background: none; }` . Tried it last week, couldn't find any way of doing it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
:not(nav) > .container
```

Note that this won't work if the container isn't directly within the nav, but there are ways around that.

Comment: If is not direct child but is descendant you can use `:not(nav) .container`

Comment: @blonfu That won't work; it'll actually select all .containers, since they all have a parent that is not a nav (namely, the body).

Comment: Thanks Noah, work like a charm for me :) And i confirm that blonfu solution is not working

Comment: Its true, you are right. I should have tried before saying anything. Sorry :$