# SCSS - exclude specified containers from a set of styles

Tags: html, css, sass, html-lists, frontend

A problem I've hit many times with ul elements (given the fact that are so often used for semantic purposes and styled dramatically, e.g. top navigation), is that attempting to set general styles for the textual use of ul elements is very fiddly to avoid messing up the other uses, or vice versa. Generally, I solve this problem by just having a dedicated set of styles included within the main page content wrapper, e.g.:

```
#page-wrapper {
    ul, ol {
        padding-left:1.6em;
    }
}
```

But the problem I've hit is that within the main page wrapper, ul elements used for specific purposes (e.g. by plugins like *chosen*), have their own set of purely cosmetic styles applied. It would be nice to have a clean way of solving this problem. Previously, like back when writing raw CSS, I would have to explicitly re-override the styles again, like:

```
.chosen-container ul {
    padding-left:0;
}
```

But this, especially doing it for every element, seems very messy. I tried the following:

```
#page-wrapper {
    :not('.chosen-container') {
        ul, ol {
            padding-left:1.6em;
        }
        ........
    }
}
```

... but it had the effect of neutralising all ul element styles everywhere.

Has anyone come up with an elegant solution to this? Googling and searching here have so far been fruitless.

Comment: This cuestion is similar to yours: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37643853/css-selector-all-except-ones-in/37643950#comment62767858_37643950

Comment: Okay so based on the solution to that question I tried `:not('.chosen-container') > { ul { ... } }` to no avail. Just removes all ul styles, even the ones outside of chosen containers (although I can't get my head round why).

Comment: Can you compile your code? I get an error for the quotes. I have to put `:not(.chosen-container)`

Comment: Look this example: https://jsfiddle.net/blonfu/hktdc04d/

Comment: @blonfu Strangely I can compile both with and without the quotes. And the jsfiddle still removes all the raw UL styling...

Comment: but my fiddle works fine, or not? The lists without `.chosen-container` parent have background red

Comment: It works in the fiddle - not sure why it doesn't work on my implementation. If I copy your code exactly (and remove all of mine), my chosen lists all have red backgrounds too!

Comment: you try with all my code, HTML and SCSS? or only the SCSS?

Comment: HTML as well. Could it be related to the sass compiler? Can't see anything wrong with the output:   `#page-wrapper :not(.chosen-container) > ul,
  #page-wrapper :not(.chosen-container) > ol {
    background: red; }`

Comment: the output is correct

Comment: if I can't reproduce the error I don't know how can I help you. The code works for me

Comment: can you show all your code? There must be something more interfering

Comment: sounds like your dom is corrupt (missing a closing tag), and you browser is closing a tag in the wrong place.... maybe )

Comment: This sounds like you're asking for opinions or lists, both of which are kind of off-topic. What are your criteria for selecting the "correct" answer?

Answer (score 1):

Generally I write it in reverse. Set the defaults to zero, then add bullets and padding only for very specific contexts.

Almost all plugins will set your LI to display:block and/or float:left.  This should drastically reduce the number of times you have to remove bullets in your css.  It's a bit less code to maintain, but does require that you have some control over the html so you can add a selector on the text container or on the list which requires bullets.

Here'an example.  https://jsfiddle.net/L252LwL0/

```
ul { margin:0; padding:0; list-style-type:none; }
li { display:block; }

.textblock ul { padding: 0 40px; list-style-type:circle; }
.textblock li { padding: 10px 0; display:list-item;  }
```

Usually I change the color of the bullets too.  Just because it's a tiny bit of branding. https://jsfiddle.net/L252LwL0/1/

To be clear, I am suggesting you remove all styles from all the ULs, then add back just once, the one that you need.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution could be to add `:not([class])` which will exclude all elements with a class.

https://jsfiddle.net/kLLky4zL/

```
div:not([class]) {
  background: blue;
}
```